# Creating cloudformation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

So i am using the https://github.com/commonsearch/cosr-ops/ deployment tool for commonsearch. The tool creates clusters/instances in CloudFormation!

I had quite a few bugs with it, witch i fixed myslef, but this one i have been hitting my head for 2 days now.

Some things fail to CREATE, when calling `make aws_elasticsearch_create`
Error listed below, any ideas?

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [ElasticsearchLbLaunchConfiguration, ElasticsearchMasterLaunchConfiguration, ElasticsearchDataLaunchConfiguration]. . Rollback requested by user.
```

I resolved this by changing MAPPINGS ami's.

BUT!

Ran into antoher problem.

This time its not the Configs, but the Scalings.

See below:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [ElasticsearchLbAutoScalingGroup, ElasticsearchMasterAutoScalingGroup, ElasticsearchDataAutoScalingGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.
```

Any ideas are welcome. Help a fellow programmer sort this out :)

Comment: Note that errors are from cloudformation website( in the processs of creation ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got progress!

You must signal the AutoScaling resources from local konsole, fot them to proceed. Heres how you do it:

```
aws cloudformation signal-resource --stack-name search-elasticsearch --logical-resource-id ElasticsearchDataAutoScalingGroup --status SUCCESS --unique-id ElasticsearchDataAutoScalingGroup
```

I have alredy next error, but its validation error. Will try to figure it out.

Comment: Instead of reporting "--status SUCCESS", you could get the result of a prevous command with '--status $?'. Like 'curl http://localhost:9200'

Comment: Did you figure out the validation error? I am trying the same thing now, and your command worked but I am not sure about fixing the validation error.